# XIB Compiler Error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Getting a "Pattern colors are not supported by the iPhone SDK for iPhone OS versions prior to 3.0." error from Xcode when compiling an application for iPhone OS 2.2.1. I'm using Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard.

The interesting thing is that others (I don't know host OS or Xcode version) are compiling this code fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any pattern colors in the XIB? Those would include things like the pinstripe background.  This XIB probably would compile with the 3.0 SDK. Like the compiler says, they're not supported in versions before 3.0.

Comment: I think that's the answer. Not going to work. Decision made last night to not support prior to 3.0, so moving forward. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify **manson's** answer, open the problem XIB in Interface Builder, then select Window|Document Info from the menu; from there you can set the Deployment target.

Answer (score 3):

in  interFace Builder -  try to set   Deplouyment Target   to OS 3.0 and height 
in my case  its work

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten the same error when trying to compile a XIB with pattern colors using 3.1.2.  The XIBs compiled fine using 3.0, but when I upgraded to 3.1.2 I started getting the error "Pattern colors are not supported by the iPhone SDK for iPhone OS versions prior to 3.0."

I have not found a solution to this problem and had to remove the pattern colors from my XIBs.

Comment: "The XIB file has a separate deployment target setting.

Open the problematic XIB file in Interface Builder. Go to Window -> Document Info. There you should see two additional development and deployment target settings, specifically set for the XIB file. At some point these appears to have been set for this XIB file to iPhone OS 2.x.

Resetting these to "default" rather than their fixed settings solves the problem handily."

Answer (score 0):

click Xib-->Show the file inspector--->Interface Builder Document --> deplooyment (use your version)

hope it helps you